# Pass and Return value from Javascript to VBScript, Vice Versa in ASP

Tags: javascript, vbscript

My code is below, I would like to make this work because my existing webpage that I am working at mostly uses VBScript. I am using ajax to query values to SQL. I would hate to change most of the code so I was just wondering if it would be possible to put back a return value from javascript to vbscript like my code below.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT">
Sub check()
    Dim a
    Dim b
    a = 1
    b = retValue a
    MsgBox b

End Sub

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

function retValue(a){
    return a + 1;
}
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Only Internet Explorer 10 and lower support VBScript. It's time to bite the bullet and migrate the legacy code. (While you are at it, it is time to stop using HTML 3.2)

Comment: Hi, it is not my call. I am just a mere programmer trying to support multiple applications and trying to make something that works, to still work.

Comment: That's not related to classic ASP, which is using **server side** vbscript. Tag removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible.

You have 2 issues in your script.

- Your Script tag for vbscript does not have `</script>`
- retValue is a function. you need to pass the arguments with in ( )

I tried to call `check` & it shows the msgbox with the text `2`

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT">
    Sub check()
        Dim a
        Dim b
        a = 1
        b = retValue(a)
        MsgBox b

    End Sub

    </script>
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

    function retValue(a){
        return a + 1;
    }
    </SCRIPT>
```