# passing value from javascript to vb scipt in classic asp and calling vb script SUB in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, vb.net, vbscript, asp-classic

I need to pass a value from javascript to a  vb script sub procedure. Also I need to access that VB SUB in Javascript.

I'm working with classic asp.

I tried using session, but its not working.

Comment: have you though of a very simple google search .. doing one yielded the following. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29495561/pass-and-return-value-from-javascript-to-vbscript-vice-versa-in-asp

Comment: Client side VBScript?  If it's server-side, then you want to send a http request with your data to the server.

Comment: @James - This question refers to classic asp so I'd guess we're talking about server side code, although it would help if the OP could provide some code to give an idea of what he's trying to do.  There's no evidence that this has anything to do with either c# or vb.net and these tags should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script  language="vbscript">

Sub Test1 ( Msg )
  MsgBox Msg
End Sub

Call Test1( "VBScript hello" )

</script>

<script language="javascript">

  Test1("JavaScript hello");

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript  is a client Side script and VbScript is a serverside script when associated with ASP. So **you have to use AJAX call** to server if you want to call functions after page load.